# How to compile and build UI form generated from intellij with plain gradle cli?

Tags: swing, gradle, intellij-idea

I have generated simple UI with intellij IDE GUI form. The resulted java file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class App {
    private JButton buttonMessage;
    private JPanel panelMain;

    public App() {
        buttonMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello world");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new App().panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

also my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3")

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:32.1.1-jre")

    // ADDED DEPENDENCY HERE
    implementation("com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3")
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass.set("com.example.j3.App")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

now even though added dependency

```
implementation("com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3")
```

as suggested here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206152369-idea-IC-gradle-and-swing-forms, after building and running the jar, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.j3.App.<init>(App.java:12)
    at com.example.j3.App.main(App.java:22)
```

which makes sense as I see no initialization of `panelMain` in constructor, but being used uninitialized (and thus null) in `new App().panelMain`. But if I try to initialize the `panelMain` in constructor as `panelMain = new JPanel();`, then the IDE complains:

```
Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer
```

So at one hand UI designer will try to initialize the UI-generated fields (`buttonMessage` and `panelMain`) at build time, but on the other hand it will not inform of doing so to the gradle. so if I `gradle clean build` and then `java -cp app/build/libs/app.jar com.example.j3.App`, then I get nullpointer exception as the `gradle build` does not take into account intellij designer initializations. So is there even solution to this?